# Using on hover to set variable to true jquery

Tags: jquery, boolean

I'm my question is simple, but it is eluding me greatly.  I'm using a jquery function to make an element flash while a variable is false, and hide when true:

```
function flasher(bl){
    if(!bl){
    setInterval(function(){
            $(".flash").fadeToggle("slow");
            }, 300);
    }
}
var bl = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flash").on("hover", function(){
        bl = true;
    });

        flasher(bl);
});
```

When I use alert, it does show the function running and I get true, but I'm unable to see my mistake in this.  Using firebug the value of bl stays false.  I've tried global bl and var bl, but all stays the same.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
function flasher(){
      setInterval(function(){
         if(!bl){
              $(".flash").fadeToggle("slow");
         }
      }, 300);
}

var bl = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flash").hover(function(){
        bl = true;
    }, function() {
        bl = false;
    });
    flasher();
});
```

Comment: I do not know where to set this accept, I'm always very courteous to those that help, their help is greatly appreciated and I rely on this site a lot both in help and learning.  Acceptance complete, and again thanks to all

Comment: Something more I must be missing, as the value of bl stays false always.  @Rodik, yours works but not with the boolean I have to use.

Comment: Sorry, bl shouldn't be pass to flasher function. See my last edit.

Comment: If bl is pass to function, it has a function scope with start value and when you listen hover event, you change bl value with global scope.

Comment: That I understand, but I'd think the variable bl would have to be passed to the function?  Obviously you're right, as it works.  I'm just trying to absorb as much information as I can.  Thank you again

Comment: No, when you declare a variable outside a function, it is available throughout the script. It's a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that your ready function only runs once, at the beginning, and hence your function flasher only runs once.

you need to run it every time you change the variable's state.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var interval;
    $(".flash").on("hover", function(){ // hoverin
        interval = setInterval(function(){
               $(".flash").fadeToggle("slow");
            }, 300);
    }, function(){ // hoverout
        clearInterval(interval);
        $(".flash").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

Also, in your interval you use a 300ms interval, and your fadeToggle is slow (which is 600ms). this means that your fade animation isn't over when you're already starting the next one. your animations will be scrambled up and continue flashing for a few seconds even after you clear the interval.

Also Also, as you have already been told, if you intend to keep using StackOverflow for help, you should follow it's rules, and accept valid answers.